# SQL Server Database is corrupted

Tags: sql-server, corruption

Unfortunately hard disk of my system is damaged, now I recovered my database. But it cannot be attached again to SQL management studio 2005.
The error is:

```
myfile.mdf is not a primary database file. (SQL server , error 5171)
```

Comment: Restore it from daily backups.

Comment: Possibly better suited for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Chances are that your database file was damaged too. I would try to perform complete database recovery (if possible) from backup.

Comment: how you are attaching the database ?? are you missing the .LDF file ?

Comment: it seems the mdf file is corrupted.Please try restoring from recent backup.Please see below link which has similar solution. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1380469-2893-1.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You should restore it from your backup (which you can do by right clicking on "Databases" and selecting restore database)

Answer (score 5):

> the error is myfile.mdf is not a primary database file.

It means the original database had more files. You need to attach *all* files, including the log (*.ldf) and secondary files. Usually these are named *.ndf but in your case they appear to had been named *.mdf, like the primary. It can also happen that you renamed files during your 'recovery'.

If the file name is correct and truly is the original primary file yet it refuses to attach it may be that is corrupted and all data on it is lost. You need to restore from a backup or recreate the DB and re-enter the data again.