# How do I fix the Failed to retrieve data for attaching mdf file is which not primary database file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, attach

I'm using SQL Server 2019 in Windows 10 Enterprise and Administrator user
I have an MDF file and I want to attach it, and it has full access in the form of Everyone Full Control , when I try to attach it I get this error :[image]

full message :

```
    ===================================

Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

------------------------------
For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.Process(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.AttachDatabaseData.PrimaryFile.GetOriginalDatabaseName(String primaryFilePath)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.AttachDatabaseData.PrimaryFile.PopulatePrimaryFileData(String primaryFilePath, Boolean isXIPath)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.AttachDatabaseData.PrimaryFile..ctor(SqlManagementUserControl parent, CDataContainer dc, String fullPath, String databaseOwner, ServerConnection connectionInfo, Boolean isXIPath)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.AttachDatabase.AddPrimaryFile(String fullPath, String fileName, Boolean isXIPath)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.AttachDatabase.buttonBrowse_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

===================================

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.GetExecuteReader(SqlCommand command)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteReader(String sqlCommand, SqlCommand& command)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecuteSql.GetDataReader(String query, SqlCommand& command)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataProvider.SetConnectionAndQuery(ExecuteSql execSql, String query)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecuteSql.GetDataProvider(StringCollection query, Object con, StatementBuilder sb, RetriveMode rm)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlObjectBase.FillData(ResultType resultType, StringCollection sql, Object connectionInfo, StatementBuilder sb)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlObjectBase.FillDataWithUseFailure(SqlEnumResult sqlresult, ResultType resultType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlObjectBase.BuildResult(EnumResult result)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.PrimaryFile.GetData(EnumResult erParent)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData(Request req, Object ci)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.GetData(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.Process(Object connectionInfo, Request request)

===================================

H:\GHAEM\neginsql.mdf is not a primary database file. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

------------------------------
For help, click: https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-5171-database-engine-error

------------------------------
Server Name: SERVERX
Error Number: 5171
Severity: 16
State: 1
Line Number: 1


------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.GetExecuteReader(SqlCommand command)
```

also I tried with the SQL Server 2008R2 , same error !

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this as well. Are we the only two people on the planet experiencing this issue with an .mdf file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server Database is corrupted](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74625/sql-server-database-is-corrupted)